# Passing Moqs It.IsAny<string> as method argument

Tags: c#, moq

First some information about my development environment:

- .Net Framework 4.5
- Moq 4.10
- Autofac 4.2
- NUnit 3.11

I try to mock a function that takes some string arguments and I would like to use `It.IsAny<string>()` to setup. Normally I would to that like this:

```
using ( AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose() ) {
    mock.Mock<SomeInterface>()
                .Setup( x => x.someFunction(
                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>() ) );
//...
}
```

But now I would like to call a fucntion that makes the setup, so I do not have to copy paste the code above and make my unit tests a little bit "better looking". I imagine something like this:

```
using ( AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose() ) {
    UnknownType anyString = It.IsAny<string>();
    setup( mock, anyString );
//...
}

void setup( Automock mock, UnknownType anyString ){
    mock.Mock<SomeInterface>()
            .Setup( x => x.someFunction( anyString, anyString, anyString ) );     
}
```

Does someone know a solution for that? I when I use `string` or even `var` as Unknown type the variable `anyString` hold the value `null` after `UnknownType anyString = It.IsAny<string>();`. Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Further description:**

I need to specify different values for every argument. So It could look like this:

```
using ( AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose() ) {
   UnknownType string1 = It.IsAny<string>;
   UnknownType string2 = It.Is<string>( s => s.Equals( "Specific string" )  );
   UnknownType string3 = It.IsAny<string>;
   setup( mock, string1, string2, string3 );
//...           
}

private static void setup( AutoMock mock, 
   UnknownType string1, UnknownType string2, UnknownType string3 ) {
   mock.Mock<SomeInterface>().Setup( x => x.someFunction( string1, string2, string3 ) );
}
```

Comment: We had a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372226/moq-it-is-not-matching/15373406 - Just ensure that `UnknownType` is an `Expression<>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`It.*` is meant to be used as `Setup` expression arguments and not passed around as parameters/variables as, by default, they return *null*.

To the best of my knowledge, what you are requesting does not appear to be possible.

The closest thing I can think of through the use of generics is to create an extension method to act on the auto mock that takes the desired expression to mock

```
public static class AutomockExtension {
    public static Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup<T> Setup<T>(this Automock mock, Expression<Action<T>> expression) where T : class {
        return mock.Mock<T>().Setup(expression);
    }

    public static Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup<T, TValue> Setup<T, TValue>(this Automock mock, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression) where T : class {
        return mock.Mock<T>().Setup(expression);
    }
}
```

which really does not save you much in terms or repeated code as you will still have to invoke `It.*` in the expression

```
using ( AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose() ) {

    mock.Setup<SomeInterface>(_ => 
        _.someFunction(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.Is<string>( s => s.Equals( "Specific string" ),
            It.IsAny<string>()
        ) 
    );

    //...           
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

Use generics

```
void setup<T>(Automock mock){
    mock.Mock<SomeInterface>()
            .Setup(_ => _.someFunction(
                It.IsAny<T>(), 
                It.IsAny<T>(), 
                It.IsAny<T>()));     
}
```

which would then let you invoke the setup as needed like

```
using ( AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose() ) {
    setup<string>(mock);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sure this would work for my example, that was too general. I updated my question (see further description). Sorry for that...