# c#:Why when I try to use coalesce operator in a mock it doesn't work

Tags: c#, moq

Why when I am trying to use a mock like this:

```
public void Test(string param=null){
    MyMock.Setup(x=>x.foo(param ?? It.IsAny<string>));
 }
```

This obviously works fine

```
public void Test(string param=null){
   if(param==null)
      MyMock.Setup(x=>x.foo(It.IsAny<string>));
   else
      MyMock.Setup(x=>x.foo(param));
 }
```

But why is that? the "param ?? It.IsAny" returns param or It.IsAny what am I missing here?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256847/curious-null-coalescing-operator-custom-implicit-conversion-behaviour) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003652/passing-moqs-it-isanystring-as-method-argument) but I still don't get it.

Comment: Not sure this helps as I don't use Moq, but I tried the following and it coalesces as expected:
            List<int?> myValues = new List<int?>() {
                4,
                null,
                1
            };
            string Foo(int value) => value.ToString();

            myValues.Select(x => Foo(x ?? 2)).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

Answer (score 2):

When setting up Mock in Moq you actually pass not a value of function parameter (say, of tpye `T`), but an `Expression<T>`, which is then analyzed by `Moq`.
So, when you pass value `Moq` will analyze it and setup expectation for method call with that value.
When you pass `It.IsAny<T>` `Moq` will again analyze it and setup expectation without any arguments.
But when you pass your `param ?? It.IsAny<string>` `Moq` simply doesn't know how to analyze it.

Comment: In the meanwhile I played with it and found out that if I just plug in a function like this:'Func<string> f =  ()=>param ?? It.IsAny<string>();'  to 'x.foo(f.Invoke())' it works fine. So if I get it correctly the first one leave the evaluation for later and fail, and this one evaluate it on the spot?

Answer (score -1):

```
MyMock.Setup(x=>x.foo(param==null ? It.IsAny<string>:param));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Tried this, not working, and like DonaldDuck says I want to understand why.